# How can I control an IR jammer or other device remotely?

Tags: infrared

I am going to buy an IR jammer kit and hide it somewhere near the tv. I need a way to remotly activate the jammer. What are my options?

I can also purchase the ninja stealth remote but I need some device that can physically push a button on the remote and I need to be able to control that device remotely.

I have a soldering iron and I"m willing to learn and spend up to $100 on new parts or things to make this work.

There is a home theater PC that I built myself connected to the TV via HDMI, I can hide an IR jammer in there or find a USB powered one possibly?

Link to IR kit http://makezine.com/projects/ir-jammer-kit/

Other option is Stealth Remote but I need something to push the button

[http://www.amazon.com/Swamiware-NR42A-Ninja-Remote-Weaponized/dp/B005AZCGOI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005AZCGOI)

The basic idea is I want to set up an IR device near the tv and be able to control it from another room or another level of the house. There is also a wifi router near the tv, something that connects to an open port on the router would allow the tv to be controlled from anywhere.

Comment: I did some digging and found this IR repeater, it's designed to let you control things through walls, like if you have a home theater setup on the other side of the wall or behind a wall http://www.amazon.com/Infrared-Extender-Receiver-Emitter-Repeater/dp/B00AMTRR5K

Comment: Are you hoping to buy something off the shelf that you can just plug in and turn on? Or do you want to learn how to incorporate a wireless module (like bluetooth) into your own embedded application?

Comment: I am sure there are simple IO boards available that can be connected to Ethernet. Here is the first one I found:
http://www.saelig.com/IO/BRD017.htm

So you could have an IO on that board turn on your jammer that you build from the kit. I am sure there are relay boards available, too. Very similar to this, but with relays instead of IO pins. Maybe that would be easier, since the relay could be wired in parallel with the switch from the jammer board.

Comment: so far I've seen a IR extender/repeater that works through RF but I'd like something that I can plug into my router so I can transmit IR signals through my intranet from another room. Seems the only way to do this would be a arduino or raspberry pie with some other components and tweaking, there doesn't seem to be a ready made product I could find for this but I'll try to do some more digging.

Comment: Here is a product that powers through usb, except it the reciever end is also wired into it, I need two ends that both plug into usb, one to the PC near the TV (to receive and repeat the signal) and the other on a PC in another room to send the signal from. That product does not work through Wifi or with a PC just gets power through USB

Answer (score 1):

You may use any type of RF to control this. Arduino has a lot of material on this, or you can for example use a Bluetooth Low Energy [Smart Beacon Kit](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&keywords=smart%20beacon) for the hardware (modify its firmware) and control this with your android/iphone with Nordic Semiconductors already ready to use apps. I recommend the [nRF UART](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordicsemi.nrfUARTv2&hl=en) app on Android since you can customize it to send whatever you want.

You want to connect one of the GPIO's of such a kit to the button of the IR jammer (remove said button, connect your GPIO to the input of the microcontroller within the kit and connect their grounds together) and you will be able to "push the button" from your cell phone.

There are also a lot of Arduino shields you can use, e.g. a [WiFi shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield), whereas you connect it the same way but you'll be able to activate the jammer from a website.